# JavaScript/jQuery Syntax error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I need some eye, I'm not seeing it right now and its making me feel foolish..

```
function whichNavToLightUp()
{
    var p = location.pathname;
    p = p.substring(p.length-1) == '/' ? p.substring(0, p.length-1) : p;
    p.split('/').pop();
    p = p.substring(1);
    p = p.toLowerCase();
    $.each('.navmenu', funtion()
    {
        if($(this).attr('rel') == p)
        {
            $(this).css({"background-position":"-108px"});  
        }
    });
}
```

line 9 the { after the $.each() is giving me the syntax error, but I don't see why. Where did I break it? Anyone?

Comment: function is misspelled as 'funtion' -- missing the c

Comment: the each runs through a handful of divs with the class navmenu, and reads the rel attributes where if one matches p which is gotten from the URL then it moves the position of the background of the matching div as its a sprite image.

Comment: @bbg you win the imaginary prize!! thank you. Always the most simplest things get over looked.

Comment: thank you. Only way I can think of keeping the nav Im working on to stay in its hover state if its actually on that page, kinda like how ya would do it with php and and if-else when ?location == blah

Comment: Why are you iterating the characters in the `'.navmenu'` string? And why do `p.split('/').pop();`? This has no effect in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.each('.navmenu', funtion()` should be `$.each('.navmenu', function()` (missing `c`)

Comment: Haha, sometimes looking at ones code for a long time makes you miss things like this, posting it on here and having someone else look at it, they take a completely different outlook on ones code; first person: "can't be a typo, I wouldn't do that, must be a real syntax error!", third person: "probably just a silly typo, damn noob!". I've done it myself so many times, just makes you want to punch yourself in the face! :)

Comment: @Sparky672: "funtion" v.s. "fun**c**tion". Time for new glasses?

Comment: someone gave the same answer above in the comments. But thank you the more eyes the better. :-)

Comment: sure, I was fiddling about with fancy code view, thats why it took me longer :P

Comment: Well just for going that extra mile I thank you that much more! Im actually waiting on the timmer to run out on the question so I can give it the big ol' green check :-)